# ввод данных с консоли и форматирование строки

Tags: c

Пытался в вести строку, чтоб создать файл с введенной строкой.

Но чёт не вышло `scanf` при вводе spase (нажатия кнопки ) почему-то отрубает всю введенную фразу. А `getchar` почему-то не дописывает `.txt'

Вот код :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME_FILE 256

int main()
{
    realize();
//    create_file();

    return 0;
}

int realize()
{
    char *filename;
    filename = (char*)malloc(NAME_FILE);

    printf("Введите строку названия файла(realize) :");

    int c; int sflag; int i = 0;
//    if((c = getchar()) != EOF ){
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c != ' '&& c != '\\'&& c != '/'&& c != '.' && c != '\''&& c != ';'){
            filename[i] = c; i++;
            putchar(c);
            sflag =0;
        }
        else if(sflag == 0){
            c = '_';
            filename[i] =  c; i++;
            putchar(c);
            sflag = 1;
        }
        if(c == '\n'){
            filename[i] = '.';i++;filename[i] = 't';i++;filename[i] = 'x';i++;filename[i] = 't';
        printf("Вот  ");
            break;
        }

    }

    printf("Вот строка :%s", filename);

    return 0;
}

void create_file()
{
    char *filename;
    filename = (char*)malloc(NAME_FILE);

    printf("Введите строку названия файла :");

    int c;
    if((c = scanf("%s", filename)) != EOF ) //поганый "фоварит "
        printf("%s\n", filename);
    else
        printf("filename not work");

    int i; int a;
    a = sizeof(filename);
    printf("a :%d\n ", a);

    for(i=0; i<sizeof(filename); i++)
    {

        if(filename[i] != ' '&& filename[i] != '\\'&& filename[i] != '/'&& filename[i] == '.' && filename[i] == '\''&& filename[i] == ';'){
            filename[i] = filename[i+1];
        }
        else
            filename[i];
    }
    printf("%s.txt\n", filename);
}
```

вот работа realize

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот работа create_file
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: а чему же равен sizeof(filename)?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch зависит от введенных символов.

Comment: с чего вы так решили?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Андрюх, скомпилируй и узнаешь, не надо ехидничать. Просто весь код вопроса я выложил.

Comment: ну так скомпиль и сам посмотри, что значением будет все время число 8. И не надо тут панибратствовать - я вас на мысль пытаюсь натолкнуть, что sizeof ни в одном варианте его использования не вернёт размер строки. А в данном случае он в любом случае вернёт размер указателя.

Comment: Русскими словами напишите, что вы хотите получить. (иначе не очень ясно, что в вашем коде *баг*, а что *фича*)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а чё делать то ??? как решить ??

Comment: @avp хочу вводить строку : `turieofksdhfk     asd;'.,'//\\\\f`  а на выходе получать `turieofksdhfk_asdf.txt`  ввиде чаровского массива

Comment: @timob256 использовать strlen

Comment: Я правильно понял, что пробелы надо заменять на подчеркивание, одиночную кавычку, точку, запятую, слэш и бэк-слеш удалять, остальные символы оставлять как есть, а после ввода вместо `\n` добавлять `.txt` (а теперь хорошо подумайте, этого ли вы в самом деле хотите)

Comment: @avp да, всё именно так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ОК.

Например, вашу функцию с `getchar()` можно оформить так:

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ cat t.c && gcc t.c && echo "turieofksdhfk asd;'.,'//\\\\f" | ./a.out
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>


#define FN_EXTENSION     ".txt"
#define FN_REPLACE_SET   " "
#define REPLACE_CHR      '_'
#define FN_REMOVE_SET    ".,;\\/'"
#define IN_LIMIT         (PATH_MAX - sizeof(FN_EXTENSION))

char *
get_txt_filename ()
{
  int c, n = 0;
  char *fname = (char *)malloc(PATH_MAX + 1);

  if (fname) {
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      if (c == '\n')
        break;
      if (n == IN_LIMIT ||
          strchr(FN_REMOVE_SET, c))
        continue;
      if (strchr(FN_REPLACE_SET, c))
        c = REPLACE_CHR;
      fname[n++] = c;
    }

    strcpy(fname + n, FN_EXTENSION);
    n += sizeof(FN_EXTENSION);
    fname = (char *)realloc(fname, n);
  }

  return fname;
}

int main()
{

  char *filename = get_txt_filename();

  printf("filename: '%s'\n", filename);

  return 0;
}
filename: 'turieofksdhfk_asdf.txt'
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте
(но лучше сначала прочесть соответствующую *manpage*)